# i cant get the data from PostgreSQL and display it in node JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, localhost

`index.js`

```
  const { Client }  =require('pg');
const client = new Client ({
user: 'postgres',
host: 'localhost',
database: 'test',
password: 'admin',
port: 5432,
}); 
client.connect();
module.exports.myconnection = client;
```

`app.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const port = 3000;
const app =express();
const db =require("./db");
app.use(express.json());
const interactrouter = require("./routes/interactions");
app.use("/data",interactrouter);
app.listen(port, () =>
console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`) // not single cotaions above tab 
);
```

`interactions.js`

```
const express = require ('express')
const router = express.Router()
const db =require('../db')
const { Client } = require('pg')
const client = new Client()

router.get('/',(req,res) => {
  client.query("SELECT id, decription, drugcode, diseasecode, type FROM interactions;")
.then (rows =>{
    console.log(rows);
    res.json(rows)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})

})
module.exports =router;
```

**my problem I connect to the server but I can't get the data from the database and this is my code how can I fix it thank you all**

*so how can I fix it or what I should edit I'm new in this field*

Comment: Are you facing any error ?

Comment: Please give more information as much as possible, we can help.

Comment: i cant get the data from postgress but i connect to server

Comment: @ xMayank before i edit the code yes
client query not afunction and client not defiend

Comment: ShinaBR2 what information you want
my code was run in (db,any) but i want to  convert it to client.query